# Decting the End of User input in console application in c#

Tags: c#

what i am Expecting from program is that after user press the Enter key , program detects as End of input and breaks the loop but in the list first item it receives is correct but the later items that we input , the first letter of every input was cropped from the word , for example :-

1st input => India
2nd input => China but following program takes hina 
later all inputs are in the above way . guys i am stuck here in this point of my program .

```
       List<String> keyss = new List<string>();
        do
        {
            item = Console.ReadLine();
            keyss.Add(item);
        } while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);

        foreach (var item in keyss)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

Comment: Thats because you've asked it to readkey after input and the input was absorbed with the readkey, so when you typed China, C was your readkey... and so ina<enter> was the next portion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
string item = string.Empty;
List<string> keyss = new List<string>();

while (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item = Console.ReadLine()))
{                 
    keyss.Add(item);
} 

foreach (var itm in keyss)
{
    Console.WriteLine(itm);
}
```